# Persist data to memory with a method, return it with another

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to find a way to store `locationSpecs.Neighborhood` data into a list of `Location` with the `AddLocation()` method and then retrieve that data with the `getLocation()` method which has return type `IEnumerable` of `ILocation`.

Note: the `Location` class implements the `ILocation` interface.

How can I get this to work? So far Locations returns as null.

```
    public class OfficeRentalChild : OfficeRental
    { 
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Neighborhood { get; set; }
        public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }

        public new void AddLocation(LocationSpecs locationSpecs)
        {
            Name = locationSpecs.Name;
            Neighborhood = locationSpecs.Neighborhood;
            List<Location> Locations = new List<Location>();
            Locations.Add(new Location(locationSpecs.Neighborhood));
        }

        public new IEnumerable<ILocation> GetLocations()
        {
            return Locations;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share code showing how you're trying to call the methods and what is failing?

Answer (score 1):

you need

```
  Locations = new List<Location>();
```

not

```
  List<Location> Locations = new List<Location>();
```

your current code just creates a local variable that gets destroyed at the end

but really waht you want is

```
public class OfficeRentalChild : OfficeRental
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Neighborhood { get; set; }
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public OfficeRentalChild(){
       Locations = new List<Location>();
    }
```

otherwise you will get a new List each time you call AddLocation